# "Inclusion" between higher categories of framed bordisms?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, cobordism

Let $\mathrm{Bord}_n$ be the bordism $(\infty, n)$-category of unoriented manifolds.
It can be viewed as an $(\infty, n+1)$-category whose $n+1$-morphisms are equivalences.

If $n$ is large enough, then the "inclusion" functor $\mathrm{Bord}_n \rightarrow \mathrm{Bord}_{n+1}$ is not an equivalence onto its image because there are diffeomorphisms of $n$-manifolds pseudo-isotopic to the identity but not isotopic to the identity.

Let $\xi$ be the pullback of $pt \rightarrow BO(n+1)$ along $BO(n) \rightarrow BO(n+1)$.
Let $\mathrm{Bord}^\xi_n$ be the $(\infty, n)$-category of bordisms with $\xi$-structure and $\mathrm{Bord}^{fr}_n$ be the framed version.
The functor $\mathrm{Bord}^{fr}_n \rightarrow \mathrm{Bord}^{fr}_{n+1}$ factors through $\mathrm{Bord}^\xi_n$.

Is the second functor $\mathrm{Bord}^\xi_n \rightarrow \mathrm{Bord}^{fr}_{n+1}$ in this factorization an equivalence onto its image?

(My guess would be that the answer is "no". Related question: [Version of "pseudo-isotopy $\neq$ isotopy" for (n+1)-framings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457743/version-of-pseudo-isotopy-neq-isotopy-for-n1-framings))

Comment: What is your definition of ``equivalence onto its image''?

Comment: @archipelago I meant the essential image, that is, the functor becomes an equivalence if the target is replaced by the essential image.
The essential image of a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of $(\infty,0)$-categories (= Kan complexes) is the union of the path components of $Y$ containing a point in the image of $f$.
This can be used as the beginning of an inductive definition.